# Let touches pass through in React Native Android embedded fragment?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-fragments

I have a fragment which embeds a React Native app that loads a view over a native fragment. My view is presented in both mobile platforms and works flawlessly on iOS. I was able to activate a property called [RCTRootView.passThroughTouches](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTRootView.m)

Is there a way I can let touches pass through the view to interact with the native view behind ?

My fragment was created following the steps at https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-android-fragment and added to my layout like this:

```
val reactNativeFragment = ReactFragment.Builder()
    .setComponentName("MainFABActionsContainer")
            .build()

    childFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fab_actions, reactNativeFragment)
            .commit()
```

The frame layout in my XML looks like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fab_actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been a long time but I just answer anyway in case someone encounters this issue in the future. The reason for the issue is that React Native draws everything in a custom view call `ReactRootView`. This view will implement `onTouchEvent` and return `true` which mean it will handle the touch event and not dispatch it to all the views below. To fix it, I overrided the root view's `onTouchEvent` and change the return value to `false`.

So the steps are

- Create `CustomReactFragment` like [this](https://github.com/leanh128/RNBottomSheet/blob/main/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesometsproject/CustomReactFragment.java)
- Create `CustomReactDelegate` like [this](https://github.com/leanh128/RNBottomSheet/blob/main/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesometsproject/CustomReactDelegate.java)
- Create `CustomReactRootView` like [this](https://github.com/leanh128/RNBottomSheet/blob/main/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesometsproject/CustomReactRootView.java). Note that in `CustomReactRootView`, I extend `RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView` because I use [React Native getsure handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation) for my bottom sheet, you can change it to `ReactRootView`.

Now you can replace `ReactFragment.Builder()` with `CustomReactFragment.Builder()` to start your React Native Fragment.